# Laravel check validation based on another fields

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to make `start_po_no` validation(`required_if` and `digits_between`) when `po_type` value is 1 and `use_spo` field value is 1.
Now, I'm written validation rule in request file like following:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'use_spo' => 'required',
        'po_type' => 'required',
        'start_po_no' => Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($supplierPoUse, $generatePo) {
            return request("use_spo") == 1 && request("po_type") == 1;
        }).'|digits_between:1,9',
    ];
}
```

But, this code only correct for `required_if`, but `digits_between` is still not working. I read laravel validation documentation but I'm not user how to check it correctly.

**#Edit**

But, `digits_between` validation still checking even `use_spo` or `po_type` is not 1. I want also `digits_between` validation when `use_spo` and `po_type` is equal to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the explanation, I believe you can just add the rules conditionally. No reason to make it more complicated.

```php
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'use_spo' => 'required',
        'po_type' => 'required',
    ];

    if (request("use_spo") == 1 && request("po_type") == 1) {
        $rules['start_po_no'] = 'required|digits_between:1,9';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: much better & easy

Comment: best way :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways of doing it

#### Using Closures

```
return [
        'use_spo' => 'required',
        'po_type' => 'required',
        'start_po_no' => [
            Rule::requiredIf(function () use ($supplierPoUse, $generatePo) {
                return request("use_spo") == 1 && request("po_type") == 1;
            }),
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (request("use_spo") == 1 && request("po_type") == 1) {
                    if(!(1 <= $value && $value <= 9))
                        $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
                }
            }
        ]
    ];
```

#### Using add()

Don't use  digits between just after but do it after validation rules are run.
you can add your validation after initial validation.

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);

$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    if (request("use_spo") == 1 && request("po_type") == 1) {
        if(!(1 <= $value && $value <= 9))
            $validator->errors()->add(
                'start_po_no', 'invalid start po no'
            );
        }
});

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // throw your validation exception
}
```